# Unable to submitscore or show leaderboard although I am able to sign in to Google+ successfully

Tags: android

In my activity:
public class MenuActivity extends Activity  implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener

And once I am connected to Google+, I try calling leaderboard. (Just for testing)

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        try{
            startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(mGoogleApiClient,'myactual_leaderboard_id'), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
        } catch (Exception e){

        }
    }


}
```

startActivityForResult throws an NullPointerException. Required API is not requested.

In my Manifest.xml

```
  meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

I have added my numeric app_id as string in the String.xml.

Game details is in "Ready To Test" state.

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

My mistake.

Realized that I have missed out a declaration in the mGoogleAPI.
Both statement below are missing.

.addApi(Games.API) 
.addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)

Problem solved after I have added them.
Full declaration as:

```
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API, null)
            .addApi(Games.API)
            .addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN).build();
```